# Retrofit 2.X - Response vs Call - What is the recommended to use?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

Please can you explain to me the difference of "Call" and "Response" in retrofit 2.X, What is the recommended way to use? and the difference of each. For instance I want to consume a 4 API calls with coroutines at the same time some might wait for response of other API and some will not. Thank you.

Comment: What is your understanding of each? Did you read some documentation before? Here you can find the api documentation for `Call`: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html and `Response`: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html Let us know what you understand, and then we can talk.

Comment: @ChristianB Yes I read some of it, I have tried it, the only difference I can see is "Response" is less code than using "Call" that requires enqueue. So which is better to use? I am also using coroutines that possible will call at least 4 API

Answer (score 1):

They are types for different purposes, but they come hand in hand.

`Call<T>` is a container that "sends a request to a webserver and returns a response".

`Response` is a container that delivers a result back to you, either from calling `enqueue(Callback<T> callback)` (asynchronously) and implementing `Callback<T>` or by calling `execute()` (synchronously). A Response can be either successful or a failure.

In other words, first you do a `Call` and then you get back a `Response`.

**Documentation**

- [Call](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html)
- [Response](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Response.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Call` --> When you wanna use request callback for error or response, you can use that. it's useful for tracking request status if it is successful or failed.

```
call.enqueue(object : Callback<T> {
     override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
         // in response
     }
    
     override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
         // in error
     }
})
```

`Response` --> When you wanna use kotlin Coroutines or RxJava in your project, it's strongly recommended to use Response. It's very very fantastic experience to use that for working with asynchronous tasks...

```
suspend fun getUsersFromServer(): List<User> {
    var users = ArrayList<User>()
    val response = retrofitService.getUsers()
    response.body()?.let {
        users = it
    }
    return users
}
```